# Switch miss first call. Android

Tags: android, uiswitch

I want to rebuild this app https://github.com/SheldonNeilson/Android-Alarm-Clock 
And change CheckBox to material Switch https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary.

Set OnCheckListener. 
My problem. When I start app. And CheckOn some alarm, onCheckListener miss this first call. After that, they work normally.

If first action CheckOff - No problem.
Problem in first call if I want to turn On my alarm.

Please open my eyes.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (null == view)
        view = LayoutInflater.from(alarmActivity).inflate(
                R.layout.alarm_list_element, null);

    final Alarm alarm = (Alarm) getItem(position);

    final Switch checkBox = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switch_alarm_active);
     checkBox.setChecked(alarm.getAlarmActive());
     checkBox.setTag(position);
     //checkBox.setOnClickListener(alarmActivity);
    checkBox.setOncheckListener(new Switch.OnCheckListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheck(Switch aSwitch, boolean b) {
            Toast.makeText(alarmActivity.getApplicationContext(), "onClick " + b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alarm.setAlarmActive(b);
            Database.update(alarm);
            alarmActivity.callMathAlarmScheduleService();
            if (b) {
                Toast.makeText(alarmActivity.getApplicationContext(), alarm.getTimeUntilNextAlarmMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(alarmActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


    TextView alarmTimeView = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.textView_alarm_time);
    alarmTimeView.setText(alarm.getAlarmTimeString());


        TextView alarmDaysView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.textView_alarm_days);
        alarmDaysView.setText(alarm.getRepeatDaysString());


    return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

try the `OnCheckedChangeListener()` like this:

```
     checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
                        //Do something..
                    }
                }
    );
```

Comment: Oh..which API version do you use?

Comment: I test the application on my phone. Its API 15. This is my gradle file http://s009.radikal.ru/i309/1507/07/808a1f253843.png .